# two ways of looping through a JavaScript array of elements with different outcomes

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

I have a question about looping in JavaScript. Mostly I use jQuery but now I've decided to make an easy game in pure JavaScript.

if I loop through all my 'td' with this method it works, The `cells[i]` are td elements and I can attach events to them.

```
    for(i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
        if(cells[i].nodeName == 'TD')
        {
            cells[i].onclick = function(){
                // call funciton on onclick
            };
        }
    }
```

But if I do like this, each element are just index numbers and the two at the end are `length` and `item`.

```
    for(var cell in cells){
        // cell is a number
    }
```

What's the difference and why doesn't the foreach-loop work like I want it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cell` is a number because it is an index to the `cells` HTMLCollection. In the second loop you'd use the values like so:

```
for(var cell in cells){
    if(cells[cell].nodeName == 'TD')
    {
        cells[cell].onclick = function(){
            GameTurnExecute(player);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: `cells` is not an `Array`, but a `HTMLCollection` or `NodeList`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also say:

```
for(var cell in cells){
    if(cells.hasOwnProperty(cell))
    {
        cells[cell].onclick = function(){
            GameTurnExecute(player);
        };
    }
}
```

not to see properties comming from prototype chain. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

In fact, almost everty time you use `for in` in javascript you want to use hasOwnProperty.

Comment: You are assuming that host object have prototype inheritance, which is not reasonable. They are not required to implement any inheritance pattern at all, and in at least one popular host environment, they don't.